# Cross-compiling ALSA-lib for Raspberry PI on eclipse windows PC

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to cross-compile alsa-lib for raspberry pi using eclipse on windows pc. I am using Sysgcc toolchain for windows used for cross-compiling on Raspberry PI.

I downloaded the alsa-lib library package from 
"https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Download" 
and copied it to my 'src' folder. I also added paths to this library as follows.

1) "Project-> Properties-> C/C++ Build-> Settings-> Cross GCC Compiler -> Includes"
and added the library path "C:\Users..\workspace\wavfileplay\src\alsa-lib-1.1.4.1"

2) "Project-> Properties-> C/C++ Build-> Settings-> Cross G++ Compiler -> Includes"
and added the library path "C:\Users..\workspace\wavfileplay\src\alsa-lib-1.1.4.1"

3) "Project-> Properties-> C/C++ Build-> Settings-> Cross G++ Linker -> Libraries"
and added "asound" in Libraries(-l) and gave the library search path for 'libasound.so' as "C:\Users..\workspace\wavfileplay\src".

But I am unable to compile the code. I removed several errors like not finding the header files by giving it the right path in different files. But now I am facing another error

expected ')' before '__SYMBOL_PREFIX'   local.h

I didn't change the local.h file as it is part of the alsa-lib library. I alsa checked the brackets and they are fine.

First, is it possible to cross-compile alsa-lib for Raspberry PI on Windows using Eclipse?

If yes, then any ideas on how to remove this error?

Thanks alot